# p5.js: Drawing tool with the possibility to change the colors

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I would like to code a drawing tool with [p5.js](https://p5js.org/).

This is my approach so far:

```js
function setup() {
  let c = createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  stroke(155, 204, 250);
  strokeWeight(20);
  c.parent('canvas');
}

function mouseMoved() {
  line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
  return false;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

#canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(240, 200, 200);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>

<div id="canvas"></div>
```

Now, I would like to add the following functions:

- If the page reloads, a random pen color should be used, from a row of
  prepared color values.
- If `mousePressed()`, another color value of the row of the prepared
  color values ​​should continue the drawing.

I started with this:

```
function setup() {
  let c = createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  c.parent('canvas');
  let colors = ['155, 204, 250', '205, 104, 200', '205, 104, 200'];
  let color = random(colors);
}

function mouseMoved() {
  stroke(color);
  strokeWeight(20);
  line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
  return false;
}
```

My approach seems to not work at all. Does anyone can help me with this please? I would be very thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

1. the scope of your `color` variable is the `setup()` function so it is not valid to access it from the `draw()` function. You need to declare this variable at the top level for it to be accessible in both.
2. The p5.js `color()` function does not work with strings containing comma separated RGB values. If you want to use strings you either need to use color names or hex codes. However, if you want to use numeric RGB values you could use arrays and the spread operator (see below).

```js
let colors;
let color;

function setup() {
  let c = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  colors = [[155, 204, 250], [205, 104, 200], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255]];
  color = random(colors);
}

function mouseClicked() {
  color = random(colors);
}

function mouseMoved() {
  stroke(...color);
  strokeWeight(20);
  line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much <3

Comment: I posted here a further issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70357443/p5-js-drawing-tool-doesnt-work-well-on-mobile-devices – Would be very nice if you could help me again!